# Sending SMS through PHP and curl (invalid number status 400)

Tags: php, api, curl, sms

I want to send SMS through PHP and curl. But its response is

> "status :400", invalid number , data: null".

Please check my code that what I am doing wrong. Here is my code.

```
$number='*****';
$toPost = array(


"Authkey"=>"******",
"Mask"=>'*****',
"user" => $username,
"pass" => $password,
"to" => $number,
"sender" => urlencode($from),

"text" => urlencode($message),


);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://buy.techsolsms.com/api/v1/quicksms.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $toPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // If you use this line, you will get response from API in $result below.


$result = curl_exec($ch);



echo "<span class='alert alert-success'> '$result'</span>" ;
echo "<script>alert('$result')</script>";

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You may have an `unescaped` character on the message. Do you also get an error sending a simple msg like `hello` ? - Note: the website has several broken links - http://buy.techsolsms.com/signup.php or http://buy.techsolsms.com/Login-Area.php - Make the service is running as expected.

Comment: I just typed "test" or "test message" in the message.

Comment: please read: "Make **sure** the service is running as expected

Comment: Ok I am will try. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Status 400 - HTTP code, Bad request (invalid number)

Check the API documentation, may be you send phone-number in invalid format.